# Clipboard API - Copy anchor tag href URL returns writeText undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am working with the clipboard API to copy the anchor URL on click of that element. However, I am getting **`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')`** is undefined.

How can I solve this?

I want to copy the HREF innerText the **https://google.nl** URL on **click**.

```
const sharePostLink = document.querySelector('[aria-role="share-link"]');

if (sharePostLink) {
    sharePostLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        navigator.clipboard
            .writeText(sharePostLink)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(
                    `"${sharePostLink}" was copied to your clipboard.`
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(
                    `Error copying text to clipboard: ${err}`
                );
            });
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
        <article class="card" aria-role-card="light">
            <div class="card__body card__body--downloadable">
                <header class="card__header">
                    <h4 class="card__title">Camp</h4>
                </header>

                <div class="card__actions" aria-role="card-actions">
                    <ul class="card__socials" aria-role="card-socials">
                        <li class="card__item">
                            <a href="https://google.nl" class="card__link" aria-role="share-link">
                                <span class="card__icon card__icon--link"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="card__item">
                            <a href="!#" class="card__link">
                                <span class="card__icon card__icon--facebook"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="card__item">
                            <a href="!#" class="card__link">
                                <span class="card__icon card__icon--twitter"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="card__item">
                            <a href="!#" class="card__link">
                                <span class="card__icon card__icon--linkedin"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is your site https? I believe this object requires a secure origin (HTTPS or localhost) if so did you grant permission for this interface? - I'm reading between the lines.

Comment: @Adrian working localhost with LocalWP and HTTP. I am working in Chrome

Comment: The [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) is only available in secure context (https).

Comment: @Christopher oke good to know!